# How to select ids which contain multiple tags?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL table with the following structure:

```
tag    article_id
```

```
Cat    1
Cat    2
Dog    3
Dog    1
Bird   3
Mouse  4
Bird   1
```

I need to get ID of article that have Cat and Bird tags simultaneously. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select id from tablename
where tag in ('Bird','Cat')
group by id
having count(distinct tag)=2
```